# Javascript Automate Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm just getting started with Javascript and I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

As a template, I downloaded a highlighting extension for chrome and am using it's code to start off. I wanted to automate one of the features in the plugin, which is that in order to start highlighting you have to type a word and press "save" in the options page.

I was able to automatically insert the words in the text box so you don't have type them in, but you still have to press the save button. Does anyone know how to automate this feature so you don't have to do that? Thank you!

Common.js:

```
function loadOptions() {
    if ("undefined" != typeof localStorage) {
        document.getElementById("textareaKeywords").value = "wikipedia";
        document.getElementById("colorForeground").value = "#000000";
        document.getElementById("colorBackground").value = "#ff0000";

        var showOccurrences = false;
        showOccurrences = "true" == showOccurrences || null == showOccurrences;
        document.getElementById("checkboxShowOccurrences").checked = showOccurrences;
    }
}

function saveOptions() {
    if ("undefined" != typeof localStorage) {
        localStorage.setItem("keywords", document.getElementById("textareaKeywords").value);
        localStorage.setItem("foreground", document.getElementById("colorForeground").value);
        localStorage.setItem("background", document.getElementById("colorBackground").value);
        localStorage.setItem("showOccurrences", document.getElementById("checkboxShowOccurrences").checked);
    }
}
```

Options.js:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    loadOptions();

    document.getElementById("buttonReset").addEventListener("click", function() {
        loadOptions();
    });

    document.getElementById("buttonSave").addEventListener("click", function() {
        saveOptions();
    });
});
```

Content.js:

```
function keywordsHighlighter(options, remove) {
    var occurrences = 0;

    // Based on "highlight: JavaScript text higlighting jQuery plugin" by Johann Burkard.
    // http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html
    function highlight(node, pos, keyword, options) {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.className = "highlighted";
        span.style.color = options.foreground;
        span.style.backgroundColor = options.background;

        var highlighted = node.splitText(pos);
        /*var afterHighlighted = */highlighted.splitText(keyword.length);
        var highlightedClone = highlighted.cloneNode(true);

        span.appendChild(highlightedClone);
        highlighted.parentNode.replaceChild(span, highlighted);

        occurrences++;
    }

    function addHighlights(node, keywords, options) {
        var skip = 0;

        var i;
        if (3 == node.nodeType) {
            for (i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
                var keyword = keywords[i].toLowerCase();
                var pos = node.data.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword);
                if (0 <= pos) {
                    highlight(node, pos, keyword, options);
                    skip = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (1 == node.nodeType && !/(script|style|textarea)/i.test(node.tagName) && node.childNodes) {
            for (i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
                i += addHighlights(node.childNodes[i], keywords, options);
            }
        }

        return skip;
    }

    function removeHighlights(node) {
        var span;
        while (span = node.querySelector("span.highlighted")) {
            span.outerHTML = span.innerHTML;
        }

        occurrences = 0;
    }

    if (remove) {
        removeHighlights(document.body);
    }

    var keywords = options.keywords.split(",");
    delete options.keywords;
    addHighlights(document.body, keywords, options);

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        "message": "showOccurrences",
        "occurrences": occurrences
    });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if ("returnOptions" == request.message) {
        if ("undefined" != typeof request.keywords && request.keywords) {
            keywordsHighlighter({
                    "keywords": request.keywords,
                    "foreground": request.foreground,
                    "background": request.background
                },
                request.remove
            );
        }
    }
});

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    "message": "getOptions",
    "remove": false
});
```

I apologize if I just put WAY too much code in here, I didn't know what or how much I would need to change or where.

Comment: Automate what exactly? When exactly should things be “saved”?

Comment: Automating `save` button click as in call `saveOptions()` function at the end of `loadOptions()` ?

Comment: Quick hack: `document.getElementById("buttonSave").click()`

Comment: It appears the saveOptions() function doesn't get called, or at least doesn't do anything when I call it. I've tried using console.log() and they never go off either, which really confuses me.

Comment: I want things to be saved every time you install the plugin, so every time you look up Wikipedia it will always be highlighted, instead of having to go into options and push save first.

Comment: Guys it still doesn't work, I've tried all your ideas. What do I do??